# Adding a button listener in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a button listener to a fragment view in Android. When I tap the "Like" or "Dislike" buttons, nothing appears to happen. I don't get the "dislikeClicked" or "likeClicked" in my Logcat view.

Here is my code:

```
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        queryForData();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view1,  container, false );
        likeButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view1_likeButton);
        likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("likeClicked", "");
                like();
            }
        });
        dislikeButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.view1_dislikeButton);
        dislikeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("dislikeClicked", "");
                dislike();
            }
        });
    return rootView;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Nothing seems obviously wrong to me. You might use breakpoints to confirm that your problem is not with your logging, and you might use Hierarchy View to determine whether your UI is set up as you think it is.

Comment: My issue was with the Log.d. Apparently, you must have something in the second argument, so I just put Log.d("dislikeClicked", "a");  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is the first parameter of `Log.d` is a tag, the second parameter is the message.

Comment: Yes add the 2nd parameter to `Log.d`. Also, you can create Toast in the `onClick` methods to get instant feedback if your onclick methods are firing.